# mod_rewrite RewriteEngine On not working

Tags: xampp, apache2.4

I've set up XAMPP on my pc recently and tried to use url rewriting.

AllowOverride is set to All.

Excerpt from my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so

DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So I made a subfolder named D:/xampp/htdocs/test/ and created a .htaccess-file in it which looks like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

Also i put an empty index.php in the same folder.
The rewriting doesn't work. I can access localhost/test/ and get a blank page but writing anything after test/ results in an 404 error ...
I don't see anything in any log-file (access/error)

Stats:

Windows 10 Home
XAMPP 7.0.6
Apache 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling XAMPP on C:\ seemed to have solved the problem.